# Viewport CSS blocked by Blogger?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-8.1, blogger

I am trying to get my personal blog, hosted on Blogger, to properly respond to the Windows 8 IE snap feature. Online research has dictated that I should add a @viewport to CSS.

However, it seems that the CSS for the @viewport is being overwritten somehow - I tested part of the blog source code on a separate file and it loaded fine, so something is happening with Blogger.

To clarify:

- Blog properly responds to a normal desktop browser and mobile devices
  (IE 11 desktop and IE 11 mobile).
- Blog does not properly respond when snapped in Metro IE - instead,
  the website is scaled.
- Adding @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } in CSS should disable
  Metro IE's automatic scaling.
- When @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } is added to Blog, blog
  continues to be scaled by Metro IE.
- However, when testing the < head > code locally, the local file is
  not automatically scaled by Metro IE (expected result)

Here is the blog in question: http://robomwm.blogspot.com

I am using @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } in my CSS, which is internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing again, I was able to reproduce the issue - however, it required closing and re-opening a tab in order to reproduce it, which is why I didn't catch this the first time.

I found the markup language responsible for this issue:

```
<meta content='IE=9' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

Online research indicates that this tells IE to render in IE 9 mode, if possible. This could explain why the issue was not reproducible via a simple refresh.

I have removed this markup language for now.